# Convert co-occurrence matrix to dissimilarity matrix for MDS in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mds, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a matrix of word co-occurrence, like below. I'd like to use MDS to reduce the dimension and plot it. In sklearn there's a function `model = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity='precomputed', random_state=1)` and to apply the model `output = model.fit_transform(input)`My understanding is the input should be a dissimilarity matrix instead of the similarity one that I have. Is that correct?  Is there a function that I could use to convert this co-occurrence dissimilarity matrix?  I'm quite new to this. Many thanks for your help.

```
co-occurrence matrix :
        word1       word2      word3 ...
word1.    0           1          3
word2     1           0          5
word3     3           5          1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late, but I might have an answer to propose.

I used a similarity matrix (full of 1 in the diagonale, which is not your case), and found a simple formula to transform it into a dissimilarity matrix: (1 - cell)
However, my supervisor found another formula (I can't find back the reference) which seems to manage a diagonale with different values. I put some details [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235182/how-to-plot-a-mds-from-a-similarity-matrix/64594079#64594079), but my AWK program can't be applied to your data (as I simplified the formula to manage my case where I only have 1 in diagonale).

The formula which could work for you is :

[image: (sii + si'i' - 2 * sii')^1/2]

In my case, where the diagonale has 1, I simplified it to :

[image: (2 - 2 * sii')^1/2]

I hope it might help you ! :)
But maybe I'm wrong. If that's the case, I'm interested to know the details.